# Rendering always shows children of current page as datasource

Tags: experience-editor, components

Sitecore 9.2 (no SXA)

The code below is the `Sitecore.Pipelines.GetRenderingDatasource.GetDatasourceLocation` pipeline. The issue I am having is that if I set the datasource field, in the rendering. It always just shows the children of the current page as the datasource for the rendering.

The main issue is that the `args.ContextItemId` is set to the ID of the current page. This is what causes the issue. In my other Sitecore instances `args.ContextItemId` is always null.

I have decompiled a lot of code and I can't understand what is setting the ContextItemId. Anyone seen this issue before?

```
    public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull((object)args, nameof(args));
        foreach (string str in new ListString(args.RenderingItem["Datasource Location"]))
        {
            if (str.StartsWith("query:", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                this.AddRootsFromQuery(str.Substring("query:".Length), args);
            }
            else
            {
                string path = str;
                string contextItemPath = args.ContextItemPath;
                string contextItemId = args.ContextItemId;
                if (str.StartsWith("./", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.ContextItemPath))
                    path = args.ContextItemPath + str.Remove(0, 1);
                Item obj1 = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(path);
                if (obj1 != null)
                {
                    if (ID.IsID(contextItemId) && obj1.ParentID.ToString() != contextItemId)
                    {
                        Item obj2 = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(contextItemId);
                        if (obj2 != null)
                        {
                            foreach (Item child in obj2.Children)
                            {
                                if (child.ParentID.ToString() == contextItemId)
                                {
                                    obj1 = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(child.ID);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    args.DatasourceRoots.Add(obj1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

#### UPDATE:

I over road the `webedit:addrendering` command and `args.Parameters["contextitemid"]` has data. This is why the pipeline has it set. Now why does ClientPipelineArgs have `args.Parameters["contextitemid"]` set.

```
GetRenderingDatasourceArgs renderingDatasourceArgs = new GetRenderingDatasourceArgs(itemNotNull)
{
    ContextItemPath = args.Parameters["contextitempath"],
    ContextItemId = args.Parameters["contextitemid"],
    ContentLanguage = WebEditUtil.GetClientContentLanguage()
};
```

#### Update 2:

I think this might be a Sitecore issue. This use the 1st child node is new in 9.1 and 9.2

8.2 & 9.1

```
   public class GetDatasourceLocation
{
    /// <summary>Runs the processor.</summary>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
    public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull((object) args, nameof(args));
        foreach (string str in new ListString(args.RenderingItem["Datasource Location"]))
        {
            if (str.StartsWith("query:", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                this.AddRootsFromQuery(str.Substring("query:".Length), args);
            }
            else
            {
                string path = str;
                if (str.StartsWith("./", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.ContextItemPath))
                    path = args.ContextItemPath + str.Remove(0, 1);
                Item obj = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(path);
                if (obj != null)
                    args.DatasourceRoots.Add(obj);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

9.2 & 9.3

```
public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
{
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) args, nameof (args));
  foreach (string str in new ListString(args.RenderingItem["Datasource Location"]))
  {
    if (str.StartsWith("query:", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
    {
      this.AddRootsFromQuery(str.Substring("query:".Length), args);
    }
    else
    {
      string path = str;
      string contextItemPath = args.ContextItemPath;
      string contextItemId = args.ContextItemId;
      if (str.StartsWith("./", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.ContextItemPath))
        path = args.ContextItemPath + str.Remove(0, 1);
      Item obj1 = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(path);
      if (obj1 != null)
      {
        if (ID.IsID(contextItemId) && obj1.ParentID.ToString() != contextItemId)
        {
          Item obj2 = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(contextItemId);
          if (obj2 != null)
          {
            foreach (Item child in obj2.Children)
            {
              if (child.ParentID.ToString() == contextItemId)
              {
                obj1 = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(child.ID);
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        args.DatasourceRoots.Add(obj1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Sitecore version? SXA?

Comment: @MarekMusielak Sitecore 9.2 (no SXA)

Comment: Seems like Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.AddRendering is the only code that could set ContextItemId.

Comment: I submitted a sitecore ticket for this. It looks to be a bug with 9.2/9.3

Comment: I think your case is probably more complex, but I wrote a blog post about something which sounds similar to this a while ago: https://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/sitecore-mvc-rendering-datasources
Is there any chance, you have inadvertently set the datasource of a parent rendering?

Comment: This is a weird change. We also noticed this and it breaks stuff when trying to enforce a well organized content structure. I wonder what Sitecore wanted to achieve with this change.

Comment: I think it was added for SXA and broke stuff in regular Sitecore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was identified as a bug in 9.2 and 9.3. Reference bug #359479 with support for the proper fix.

Comment: Was there a solution/fix from sitecore for this? I'll be raising a ticket referencing your bug.

Comment: Yes, tell Sitecore support it is bug #359479

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same difference in the Process method of GetDatasourceLocation which resulted in the "Select the Associated Content" dialog to only display the first-level child. In a 9.0.1 solution, most of our renderings had datasource locations written in the following format:

```
./Components/Page Local Teasers|query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatekey='website container']/Assets/Shared Teasers
```

This resulted in two roots displayed in the associated content dialog: the "Page Local Teasers" folder and the "Shared Teasers" folder, just like we wanted it.
However, in 9.3 (and 9.2 too I assume), it results in the "*Components*" folder and the "Shared Teasers" folder which is not what we wanted (it allowed authors to add components in the incorrect subfolder).

A quick solution for us was to just append "query:" to the first expression as well, which uses the AddRootsFromQuery method that behaves just like before. So we updated the format of the datasource location to:

```
query:./Components/Page Local Teasers|query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatekey='website container']/Assets/Shared Teasers
```

This resulted in the roots "Page Local Teasers" and "Shared Teasers" just like we wanted it. Maybe this can help in your case as well?